# jQuery Ajax Post 304 file nit modified

Tags: ajax, http-status-code-304

I i added Ajax js file to my project but keep getting 304 Not Modified

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Webhook/HandleWebhook",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#customerEmail").text(data.Email);
            $("#customerName").text(data.Name);
        },
        error: function (){
        }
    });
});
```

I tried `cache=false`  and cache buster but the both way didn’t work